# Deleting all the data series in a dynamic chart

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I create a dynamic chart on multiple data series according to the selection I make in the listbox (Lbox1).

It throws an error when I delete all the data series initially to make a fresh chart.

```
Public Sub listbox_selection()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim temp As String
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim s As SeriesCollection

    k = Sheets("Plan1").ChartObjects(1).Chart.SeriesCollection.count

    ##This part giving error
    For i = 1 To k
        Sheets("Plan1").ChartObjects(1).Chart.SeriesCollection(i).Delete
    Next
    ####

    Sheets("Plan1").ListBoxes("LBox1").Select
    For i = 1 To Sheets("Plan1").Shapes("LBox1").ControlFormat.ListCount
        If Sheets("Plan1").ListBoxes("LBox1").Selected(i) = True Then
            Call Listit(X:=i)
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Public Sub Listit(ByVal X As Integer)
    X = X + 3
    With Sheets("Plan1").ChartObjects(1).Chart
        With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
           .XValues = Range("Q2:U2")
           .Values = Range("Q" & X & ":U" & X & "")
           .Name = Range("P" & X).Value
        End With    
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You should step backwards through the SeriesCollection `For i = k To 1 Step -1`

Comment: The season behind Tim's agrument is because let's say there are 3series.. you delete the seriesCollection(1) <---, the 2nd one become the 1st, te 3rd one becomes the 2nd serie. So you will get a "vba out of subscript range" error

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this,

```
Sub temp()
  ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
  For Each s In ActiveChart.SeriesCollection
      s.Delete
  Next s
End Sub
```

Comment: @ Tim ...Thanks:) ...its working ! .. I just wanted to know why it gave error in the other case.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `Sheets("Plan1").ChartObjects(1).Chart.ChartArea.ClearContents`

Answer (score 1):

Excel 2010

```
ActiveChart.ChartArea.ClearContents
```

Comment: Hi there, can you add some more details to your answer? see how to [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)